# ¿Cómo traducir "driveway"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

Un(a) `driveway` es el acceso para el coche a una casa (o más bien, al garaje o a la parte "privada" de la propiedad). Dependiendo del tamaño o tipo de casa esta puede ser más o menos larga o terminar en el garaje, patio trasero o algún otro tipo de area (que puede ser común, dependiendo del tipo de casa).

Un [ejemplo ilustrativo de *driveway*](https://www.google.com/maps/@42.3939675,-71.132102,3a,75y,287h,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sgHIdDd1zyuHDtBg2uTwNyA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1).

Sé que se llama `vado` a la parte de la acera enfrente del *driveway* que es más baja que la acera para facilitar la entrada y salida de los vehículos. Creo que se puede denominar "paso de carruajes" o "paso de vehículos" al acceso que conecta la calle con el garaje en un bloque de viviendas, pero tengo la duda de si ese término se aplicaría para un "residential driveway" como los mostrados en el link de ejemplo (es decir, el de una casa unifamiliar o un *condominio*, en lugar de un bloque de pisos).

¿Se usaría también "paso de carruajes/vehículos" o hay algún otro término más apropiado?

Comment: ¿Necesitas una palabra formal o informal? La verdad es que trabajé más de diez años en una administración de fincas y aún así no sabría decirte cómo se llama esa pequeña zona asfaltada. Si después de eso hay un garaje, patio o similar, yo usaría el nombrado paso de vehículos (es decir, si lleva a algún otro sitio, pues lo de paso se suele usar si conecta dos lugares, carretera y garaje por ejemplo); de otra forma simplemente usaría patio trasero o directamente aparcamiento, pues veo que los coches también están aparcados en él. La verdad es que donde vivo no se usan ese tipo de construcciones.

Comment: Por cierto, no sé en otros países pero en España _vado_ se usa solo cuando tienes un permiso del ayuntamiento o institución estatal similar para que nadie pueda aparcar en esa zona de la acera que da entrada al garaje. De otra forma, aunque exista esa parte más baja de la acera que mencionas, no se suele usar esa palabra.

Comment: ¿Qué tal [_salida de vehículos_](https://goo.gl/maps/HYFAjfoBX1H2)?

Comment: Mi sugerencia: camino/sendero de acceso (al garaje/a la casa)

Comment: Las sugerencias no son malas. Un término informal me basta. Sólo quiero tener un término con el que me pueda entender con la gente de España cuando quiera decir "Hoy han caído otras 10 pulgadas de nieve y me toca quitar la nieve de la _driveway_). "Salida de vehículos" no me convence del todo, porque esa sección lateral de la casa no necesariamente conduce a un garaje, aunque sí que es cierto que si se aparca ahí, es una salida de vehículos.

Comment: Pues en la ciudad donde vivo todos le decimos pasillo, pero no sabría decirte que tan regional o nacional es este término, tal vez se use sólo en mi provincia o en mi país

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien dices, un [vado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bFVAOtK) es la "modificación de las aceras y bordillos de las vías públicas para facilitar el acceso de los vehículos a los locales y viviendas". Por lo que hablaríamos de la modificación de la acera y no del camino en sí. Creo que la opción más genérica para *driveway* es ***vía de acceso***, siendo *[vía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=biXBkO2)* una "calzada construida para la circulación rodada", con lo cual hacemos referencia a un paso específico para vehículos. Opciones como "sendero" o "camino de acceso" pueden hacer referencia a caminos en general, por ejemplo para personas y no para vehículos.

Por cierto, la opción que da el traductor de Google es *entrada de coches*, aunque tal vez *entrada de vehículos* quede mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Como en Colombia nunca usamos *coche* diríamos:

- *entrada de carros*  o
- *acceso vehicular*

Comment: "Accesso vehicular" se oye elegante; francamente nunca lo he oido en Mexico (pero obviamente se podria entender).

Answer (score 1):

Yo uso

**entrada de coche**

(lo cual aprendi en Mexico)

Parece que [linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=entrada%20de%20coche) lo propone también.

Comment: En Chile se dice "entrada de auto". Es lo mismo.